# How to remove the automatically added value from <option><select> to form action url, without removing the id in the select declaration

Tags: html, forms, submit, action, form-submit

I'm actually working on a website that I have very little control over.

I have a form with a Drop down menu implemented like in the following code

```
<form method="GET" action="/particulier/fichePays">
  <select id="pays">
     <option value="1">Spain</option>
     <option value="2">France</option>
     <option value="3">USA</option>
  </select>
  <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Valider</button>
</form>
```

The problem here is, when I click on the submit button, the value of the selected option is automatically added at end of the resulted URL. For example, if i select **France**, the resulted url is

```
/particulier/fichePays?pays=2
```

Instaed of

```
/particulier/fichePays
```

I don't have a great control on the website, so for some reason, I cannot remove the **id=pays** in the select declaration.

Is there any way to remove the automatically added **?pays=valueSelected** at the end of the URL please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the method?

If yes you could use `POST` instead of `GET`.

The difference according to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) is:

GET Method:

- Appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs
- The length of a URL is limited (about 3000 characters)
- Never use GET to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL)
- Useful for form submissions where a user wants to bookmark the result
- GET is better for non-secure data, like query strings in Google

POST Method:

- Appends form-data inside the body of the HTTP request (data is not shown is in URL)
- Has no size limitations
- Form submissions with POST cannot be bookmarked

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. In fact, the problem is that, the website have not been correctly implemented. There are more than 200 countries and, for each country, there is a html file with this form and get method. Depending on the selection made before, one of those html is displayed in the browser. So, I have to change the GET by POST in any of those html files. And it is a very hudge modification. I'm looking about a something like JavaScript, to dynamically make this change

Comment: Can you share the link to the website please?

Comment: Hello sina_r. Thanks so much for your help. I have changed the GET method by POST in all my html files and it works perfectly now. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

use post method instead of get method

Comment: Please add more clarification/details to you answer.